# How to scroll to a TextView in a Column that contains Expanded items in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Say we have the code below. If I select the last TextField, the layout gets squashed because it tries to fit in the smaller space due to the keyboard showing. In order to fix this I can set the `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding` property to `false` on the parent Scaffold, but now the TextField would be hidden behind the keyboard. If I try to add a SingleChildScrollView, the Column would have infinite height, therefore making it impossible to use Expanded.

Is there any way to scroll the TextField in view while using Expanded (or another way to divide space on screen proportionally in a Scrollable Widget)? Thank you.

```
Column(
    children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
            child: TextField()
        ),
        Expanded(
            child: TextField()
        ),
        Expanded(
            child: TextField()
        ),
        Expanded(
            child: TextField()
        ),
        Expanded(
            child: TextField()
        ),
    ]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

use CustomScrollView and, restrict infinite, at end SliverToBoxAdapter, hope so it would work.

```
CustomScrollView(
slivers: <Widget>[
SliverList(),
SliverToBoxAdapter(
child: new Container(height: 2.0, color: Colors.white),
),
]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the height of the screen and divide by the number of TextFields, check this code:

```
     @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final numberOfTextFields = 5;
        final sizePerItem = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / numberOfTextFields;
        return SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
              resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: true,
              body: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: List.generate(
                    numberOfTextFields,
                    (index) => SizedBox(
                          height: sizePerItem,
                          child: TextField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(sizePerItem / 2),
                              hintText: "$index",
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                  ).toList(),
                ),
              )),
        );
      }
```